# Spread operator sin mutar elementos ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Tengo que crear una funcion que cree un nuevo array en base a los dos anteriores pero sin mutarlos.

```
function reverse(arr1, arr2) {
const arr3 = [...arr2, ...arr1];
return arr3; 
}
```

El problema es el siguiente

```
 const arr1 = [1, 2];
 const arr2 = [3, 4];

 reverse(arr1, arr2);

 arr1.toEqual([1, 2]);
```

};

no le puedo aplicar toEqual al arr1, no se si es que se desarmo cuando lo pase a la funcion reverse y le aplique el spread, pero si es asi, como puedo crear el nuevo arreglo en base a los otros dos, siendo que estos sigan siendo arreglos?

Answer (score 0):

Tu código esta correcto, solo te faltaba asignar el valor que retorna la función:

```
function reverse(arr1, arr2){
    return [...arr2,...arr1] 
}

const arr1 = [1, 2]
const arr1 = [3, 4]

const arr3 = reverse(arr1, arr2)
```